# Syntax explanation: .join(char for char in n if char.isalpha()), return n == n[::-1]

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def palindrome(n):
    n = n.lower()
    n = ''.join(char for char in n if char.isalpha())
    return n == n[::-1]
```

1. `n = ''.join(char for char in n if char.isalpha())`
2. `return n == n[::-1]`

Can someone break the syntax of these 2 lines down process by process?

Answer (score 3):

`(char for char in n if char.isalpha())` does pretty much what it says in almost-English: it creates a generator - which is kind of like an unrealised list, that you can get one element at a time from - that will yield every `char` where `char` comes from `n`, but only if `char.isalpha()` (i.e. where `char` is alphanumeric). Thus, for `n = "the meth"`, you would get `t`, `h`, `e`, `m`, `e`, `t` and finally `h`, in order (but not the space, as it is not alphanumeric).

`string.join(iterable)` can take any iterable (like a list, or a generator), and slap it together with the string between each element. If you provide an empty string, it will just smoosh up the elements of the iterable without anything in between. So you get `themeth` - the original string cleared of anything that is not a letter or a number.

`string[from:to:step]` is the way of slicing substrings from a string (or subarrays from an array). You can leave out any part of it: `"012345"[1::3]` will take every 3rd character staring from 1st (well, 2nd if you're not a computer), resulting in `"14"`. If the step is negative, then `from` and `to` defaults are reversed, and `n[::-1]` means "every -1th character from end to start", which is the word, reversed. `"themeth"[::-1]` is `"themeth"`; thus `"the meth"` is a palyndrome.

---

*) Meth is bad, m'kay? Don't smoke it, don't deal it, don't deal with it; it is here only as an easy palyndrome.

Answer (score 2):

1st line -

```
n = ''.join(char for char in n if char.isalpha())
```

`s.join(iterable)` is used to join each string in the iterable (which can be anything a list/tuple/generator expression) , using the `s` ,that is it creates a new string like - `<first element of iterable> + s + <second element of iterable> + s + ... + <last element of iterable>` . Example -

```
>>> '|'.join(['abcd','efgh','xyz'])
'abcd|efgh|xyz'
```

In your particular case , it is used to create a new string with only alphabets, removing all kinds of numbers/spaces/ etc. This is because -

You are first iterating over each character in the string using the syntax - `for char in n` . Example -

```
>>> for char in "abcd":
...     print(char)
...
a
b
c
d
```

Then you are checking if the char is an alphabet using the condition `if char.isalpha()` , `str.isalpha()` returns True only if the character is an alphabet, otherwise it returns False.

Then you are taking all chars that satisfy the above said condition. So -`char for char in n if char.isalpha()` , transforms to -

```
for char in n:
    if char.isalpha():
        char
```

The above cannot be put inside a `str.join()` , the above for loop is just an illustration of how the generator expression - `char for char in n if char.isalpha()` evaluates. The syntax is called Generator Expressions, read more about it at [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Then you join all those characters using an empty string, so that directly joins them all.

---

2nd line -

```
return n == n[::-1]
```

This checks if `n` is equal to its reverse , if it is, it returns True , otherwise False. This is because `n[::-1]` returns the string in reverse order. Example -

```
>>> n = 'abcdefgh'
>>> n[::-1]
'hgfedcba'
```

Comment: How would you format .join(for char in n:
    if char.isalpha():
        char)?

Comment: no , you cannot put the `for loop` version inside a join, it was just put to explain how the generator expression in your first case evaluates.

Comment: So this is specific syntax that allows one to use a for loop as an argument for a built in function then?

Comment: not just builtin function, its just an argument to the function, its called generator expression, read more about it [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: It can be used anywhere an iterable is expected. Search for `Python iterable` to read about what they are.